# What's the benefit of using as when creating an instance, generally inside a factory constructor

Tags: dart

```
class Product {
  final int id;

  Product({this.id});

  factory Product.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Product(
      id: map['id'] as int, // Why as?
    );
  }
}
```

This is a pattern I have seen used by Google, the main question is what's the need of using `as` there, because below code does the job equally well.

```
Product(
  id: map['id'], 
)
```

Can anyone tell me any advantage of using `as` in above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes down to how the analyzer is configured and if you have disabled `implicit-casts` in analysis_options.yaml:

```
analyzer:
  strong-mode:
    implicit-casts: false
```

The problem in your code is that the type of the `map` is defined as `Map<String, dynamic>` so we don't really know the type of the values in the map on compile time. And if we have disabled implicit casting we cannot just assign a `dynamic` into a `int` variable without any implicit type casting with `as`.

It is recommended to use `implicit-casts: false` (and `implicit-dynamic: false`) to make the analyzer more strict about your typing which can both make more readable code but only catch errors where you are casting types to other types without your knowing which in the end could have give a runtime error.

There are more about in the documentation:
https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options

Comment: That was my first thought too and I am actually using pedantic package, but it doesn't give me any warning or error when I am not using `as`. I am on `1.9.0` version

Comment: I can see the pedantic package actually does not disable `implicit-casts` or `implicit-dynamic`: https://github.com/dart-lang/pedantic/blob/master/lib/analysis_options.1.9.0.yaml . I would still assume the project, where you have found the code example, have disabled both features.

Comment: I found this kind of codes on flutter.dev webpage, where they don't follow pedantic because you'd see they keep using something like `int x = 10`.

Comment: But as we have concluded, pedantic has nothing to do with this. But it is generally seen as a good thing to use at least `implicit-casts: false` in you code which you also can see in multiple flutter guides. Also, `implicit-casts: false` will be the default when NNBD is landed so that is yet another reason to write you examples where you assumes that feature has been turned off: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/31410#issuecomment-510683629

Comment: Hi, although it's an old post, I've a doubt. If a `dynamic` is an `int` like `dynamic i = 1`, we can directly assign `i` to an `int` (both before and after null safety) without seeing a compile error. So, is there really any need of using `as` in that situation because if the `dynamic` wasn't an `int`, using `i as int ` or directly assigning `i` to an `int` will throw the runtime error.

Comment: @iDecode `dynamic i` in `dynamic i = 1` means `i` can point to any type of variable regardless of type and can be reassigned to any type afterwards. It does not change `1` is a `int` object which you can verify with `i.runtimeType`. But since we can later do `i = 'text'` and therefore change the type of `i`, we can never trust the type from a `dynamic` variable. So you should always test the variable with e.g. `as int` to tell the analyzer that you are expecting the `dynamic` variable to contain a `int` compatible object which will also add a check on runtime.

Comment: @iDecode Also, since `dynamic` can contain anything, it can also contain `null`. So that is also a reason why you need to test the value you get from a `dynamic` variable.

Comment: I think I could't make you understand my point. I already know what `dynamic` is for; all I was saying is in the given example code, even if you don't use `as`, you should still be good *because* let's say `i` being `dynamic` changes to `null` or `String` from initial `int`, either you do `id: i as int` or `id: i`, you'll get the runtime error. So, there's no need to use `as` *only* when assigning a dynamic typed to a regular type like in the given code.

Comment: @iDecode The use of `as` makes it clear that a typecast is going to happen which makes it easier to spot where runtime errors can happen. I am not a fan of automatically typecasting `dynamic` to anything. Especially when I am making a code review, I need to know when something happens which can cause a runtime exception. This is also why we use `!` with null-safety. It is to make it clear where we are doing stuff where the analyzer does not guarantee anything.

Comment: "The use of as makes it clear that a typecast is going to happen which makes it easier to spot where runtime errors can happen" -- That was needed. Thanks :)